# SpringBoot WebService client: MultipartFile and String parameters

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, jersey

I've implemented an upload REST web service using SpringBoot which receives 2 parameters:

- String message
- A file

The web service code looks as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadtest", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> upload(
                                                  @RequestParam("msg") String  msg,
                                                  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    System.out.println("uploadtest");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(singletonMap("url", "uploadtest"), HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

I am working trying to create Jersey WS client. The following code works fine when the WS receives only the MultipartFile parameter:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget webTarget
            = client.target("http://localhost:8080/uploadtest");

    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
    multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

    FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file",
            new File("/filename.xml"),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);

    Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));
```

In addition if both parameters were String the following code also works:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
    WebTarget webTarget
            = client.target("http://localhost:8080/uploadtest");

    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
    formData.add("msg", "msg1");
    formData.add("mesgbis", "msg2");

    String responseResult = webTarget.request()
            .post(Entity.entity(formData, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), String.class);
```

I would like to learn whether there is a way to create bodyPart on the MultiPart object so to create String and MultipartFile parameter. In case it is not how can I accomplish the request to the WS?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I've managed to make it work as follow:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget webTarget
            = client.target("http://localhost:8080/uploadtest");

    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
    multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

    FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = new FileDataBodyPart("file",
            new File("/filename.xml"),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

    FormDataBodyPart bodyPartMsg = new FormDataBodyPart("msg", "custom msg");
    multiPart.bodyPart(bodyPartMsg);
    multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodyPart);

    Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));
```

Comment: If you use `FormDataMultiPart` instead of just `MultiPart`, you can use the method `field(name, text)`.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, same behavior can be achieved by using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/):

```
File uploadFile = new File(pathUploadFile);
RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("msg", job.toString())
            .addFormDataPart("mesgbis", uploadFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(null, uploadFile))
            .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

String retValue = "";
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```